# Compare Array value with Object key and set the value to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I've an array and an object. I should compare the Array value with the object key. If both are matches, I should push the value of object into the array.

I've achieve this with the below logic.

```js
  var arr = [{ "name": "Coal", "segmentId": null }, { "name": "Ash", "segmentId": null }];

    var obj = {
        "Ash": {
            "October 2015": "66",
            "segmentId": "66",
            "December 2015": "435",
            "November 2015": "34535"
        },
        "Coal": {
            "October 2015": "23455",
            "segmentId": "66",
            "November 2015": "3454",
            "December 2015": "345"
        }
    };

    document.writeln("Original Array : " + JSON.stringify(arr));

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i].name === keys[j]) {
                arr[i].segmentId = obj[keys[j]].segmentId;
            }
        }
    }

    document.writeln("Transformed Array : " + JSON.stringify(arr));
```

I would like to know, Is there any other best way to handle this or any js library to make it simple?

[Fiddler Version](http://jsfiddle.net/b3r75r8x/)

Comment: perhaps look at http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: Check our the fiddler here [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/b3r75r8x/)

Comment: @ergonaut can you name the underscorejs api name to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with javascript higher order functions:

```
arr.map(function(item){
  item["segmentId"] = obj[item["name"]]["segmentId"]
});
```

Comment: Am getting two objects as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not provided a fiddle.But you can do it in jquery like below:

Please note I am creating a new array for the result set.

```
var arr = [{ "name": "Coal", "segmentId": null }, { "name": "Ash", "segmentId": null }];
var obj = {
        "Ash": {
            "October 2015": "66",
            "segmentId": "66",
            "December 2015": "435",
            "November 2015": "34535"
        },
        "Coal": {
            "October 2015": "23455",
            "segmentId": "69",
            "November 2015": "3454",
            "December 2015": "345"
        }
    };

var a=[];  
$.each(arr, function(i, v) { 
    $.each(obj, function(oi, ov) {    
        if(arr[i].name==oi)             
             a.push(obj[oi].segmentId);           
    });
});


alert(a.length);
```

Comment: Why would I use jQuery for a plain old loop?

Comment: Hi @torazaburo OP has mentioned best way or any js library.So I think he is open to jquery.He is looking for best way.I have shown him one of the way.Of course it can be further reduced down to one liner.But I dont have much time now to spend time on this.Will look later